# Mysql - Subquery with date and like

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column date (type mysql date : yyyy-mm-dd)

I have done this request:

```
Select Month(MAX(date)) AS last_month, YEAR(MAX(date)) AS last_year FROM mytable
```

to get the last year and last month.

I want for this last year and last month select all data in one request.

How can I use something like:

```
Select * from mytable where date like 'last_year-last_month-%'
```

this in sub-query ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for alls,

here is the good request :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE MONTH(date) = (select Month(MAX(date)) FROM mytable)
AND YEAR(date) = (select YEAR(MAX(date)) FROM mytable)
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick (maybe not the best performing solution though):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE MONTH(date) = (SELECT MONTH(MAX(date) FROM mytable))
AND YEAR(date) = (SELECT YEAR(MAX(date) FROM mytable));
```

EDIT: Corrected brackets.

Comment: Retrurns error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM mytable) AND YEAR(date) = (SELECT YEAR(MAX(date) FROM mytable) ' at line 3

Comment: MONTH(MAX(date)), YEAR(MAX(date)) just a minor syntax fix.

Comment: Sorry, a bracket was missing at the end of the sub select statements ... and as the column name is a reserved word (date) you should put it in  single quotes probably.

Answer (score 1):

Is the table being update continuously?
If so, then you can go without the subqueries since they will slow the query down by quite a lot.
This selects everything from the current month.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW())
AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW())
ORDER BY date ASC
```

And this one selects everything from the current and last year.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE YEAR(date) > YEAR(NOW())-1
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Comment: YES, the table is being updated continuously.
For the last year, it is ok, but when I want to select date of the last 2 years I have used this : 
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE  YEAR(date) = (select YEAR(MAX(date)) FROM mytable)
OR YEAR(date) = (select YEAR(MAX(date))-1 FROM mytable)
ORDER BY date ASC